# Clang tidy not working with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, clang

I want to run clang-tidy on an existing project while building thru MSBuild.
I have installed clang in visual studio Version 16.11.4

[image]

and following is setting for running clang-tidy

[image]

I am getting following error. Please help.

```
error MSB6003: The specified task executable "clang-tidy.exe" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
error MSB6003:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.ClangTidy.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
error MSB6003:    at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
```